# Joining two tables and fetching records in a single query in FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Hi i have written a query by which i can fetch posts,actor_id,comments and other columns required from `stream` table. But i want to fetch user's name also along with actor id and other columns in a single query. 
My queries is :

```
select message,created_time,actor_id,attachment,comments,created_time,impressions,likes,message,message_tags,place,share_count from stream where source_id in (any_page_id)
```

I want to add user's `name` also from `user` table along with this list of columns i am fetching from `stream` table in a single query so that i can handle it in a single `json` file. .

Also in comments we will get several user's id with comments as from_id. Can we get username  for this from_id also. Is this possible, i know we cannot use join in FQL. Or i am missing something or in a wrong approach. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

### Updated

Now i am able to get actor_id and other fields of the post together along with user's name at the end in the same json using multi-query. Something similar to :

```
fql?q={"query1":"select+message,created_time,actor_id,attachment,comments,created_time,impressions,likes,message,message_tags,place,share_count+from+stream+where+source_id+in(any_page_id)","query2":"select uid,name from user where uid in (*#query1* "}
```

But now i am not able to get the user's name and user's id who are there in the comments of the post in the same json.

Comment: You have th3 complete `comments object` - which is an array of the users who have commented; what else you want?

Comment: hi yeah i got the comments which is in a array, this array now contains user_ids, but i am not getting user_name. So is there any way around so that i can get user_names of those who have comented in the same json file.

Comment: I dont think you could get that in the same JSON, you have to make a seperate call for that

Comment: Yeah i also think the same. Thanks for replying. :)